# How to run script locally in python fabric also in parallel?

Tags: python, fabric

I am having following code on windows machine which connects to remote unix machine using fabric.
`hosts_file` contains list of IP address, currently I am copying `abc.sh` from windows (central server) and pushing it to remote unix machine and execute the script on unix.
Now what I am trying to do is to keep the copy of the script on windows and run it on the remote machines, also I want to do this activities in parallel on remote servers.

Would you please advise the code for the same. (trying to do something similar what ansible does)

```
from fabric.api import *
from contextlib import contextmanager
from fabric.state import env
env.skip_bad_hosts=True
def set_hosts():
env.hosts = open('hosts_file.txt', 'r').readlines()
env.user = 'root'
def deploy_script():
   put("C:/src/abc.sh","/home/mkoe",mode=755)
   sudo('./abc.sh')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think fabric has a way of doing what you want.

You can probably work around it by adding ' && rm abc.sh' to your script.

Answer (score 0):

In fabric >= 2.0, you can put local and remote machines in the same pool (if you can SSH to localhost):

```
with (fab.Connection('localhost') as cxn0,
      fab.Connection('host1') as cxn1,
      fab.Connection('host2') as cxn2):
    cxns = [cxn0, cxn1, cxn2]
        
    # prep_in_various_different_ways(cxns)
        
    pool = fab.ThreadingGroup.from_connections(*cxns)  # Or SerialGroup
        
    pool.run(...)
```